# Does move constructor have to call std::move()?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I ran into some code in our project like this:

```
class A {
public:
  A(A&& obj): valid_(false), data_(obj.data_) {}
  //...
  void print() {
    for (auto x : data_) cout<<x<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
  }
private:
  bool valid_;
  vector<int> data_;
};
```

Is this a valid implementation of move constructor? Is it a must to use `std::move()` for member variables in move constructor in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is important to remember that "lvalue" and "rvalue", and the zoo of other "*values" apply not to variables, but to *expressions*.

The expression `obj.data_` is an lvalue expression, and the easiest way to see this is to consider that `&obj.data_` is well formed, whereas taking the address of an rvalue expression is not.

To allow move semantics to apply, you must take the result of this lvalue expression and cast it via `std::move` so that it is an rvalue expression to which move semantics (for whatever type data_ happens to be) actually apply.

Therefore, yes, you must apply `std::move`.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to change `data_(obj.data_)` to `data_(std::move(obj.data_))` or it will be copy constructed; named variables are never r-value references unless explicitly moved (or forwarded under appropriate conditions); C++ won't implicitly apply `move` transitively to object attributes.